# Multiple model in a single view with user input

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to **create a page with multiple model of Child for register**.

every time when user checked yes radio button it should display another model to register same model.
so it is like

name:

firstname:

do you want another record? yes or no

if yes then again

name:

firstname:

like a loop it should keep ask while user check yes
then submit the form.

Comment: do you mean a modal form (pop up form), or are you talking about data model, which means your database model? Also, this seems like a confusing UI, since after I enter the name, and don't want to enter anymore, are you suggesting that hitting "no" will still add the name? That's going to confuse the user, since they will not know how to save the name, and they will have "no", or "add again", but the user may be done, and does NOT want to add again. So to save the current name and stop I hit no???? So, does this mean that hitting "no" will not save? And how do they cancel or not save?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: so let's say I have a CHILD model which has some elements like firstname: lastname: age: etc. and a view with that model to save data to database. we start with 1 record and if user wants to add more by clicking yes radio button they should be able to add more untill that dont want to add another record. when they finish there is a submit button where they can submit to form.  hopefully is clear now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is close to your needs.
[image]

Just note that it will submit a form like this in the end.
[image]

You will need to parse it in the api controller.

You could try the below code for a test.

```
<form>
    <div id="models">
        Name:<input name="name"/>
        First Name:<input name="fname"/></div>
    </div>
    Do you want another record?<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()">Yes, add another one</button>
    <button type="submit">No, submit</button>
</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    function add(){
        $("#models").append('<div>Name:<input name="name"/> First Name:<input name="fname"/></div>');  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. let me try that. how about if it's a model and we save records with that model? thanks